# Are there risks of exploit with uploading a file this way?

Tags: php, file

I have a simple form in PHP that make the conversion of a file from XML to SQL or vice versa. In this form, there is an input where the user can upload a file with xml or sql extension. I do various check (extension of the file and file size), I read the file using the value tmp_name of the global array $_FILES, I do some operation for the conversion, and then I save the modified file in my server (compressed in gz) with the original name of the file in the client machine in order to give the link to the user and download it.

My question are: There are risks of exploit with the steps that I listed above? In general, there are risks of exploit with uploading a file? Or risks, to upload the file with the original name in the client machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always risks of exploit when allowing users to upload files, so it's good to be worried.

You say "I do some operation for the conversion", so while I cannot comment specifically on the safety of this operation, there could be risks here depending on the operation and the content provided to it (e.g. buffer overruns, invalid data).

I'm assuming you are saving your file with a .gz extension.

Saving with the client filename could pose *compatibility* problems if you do not clean the filename at all. There are differences in disallowed (or problem) characters between filesystems, such as & in Unix or : on Windows. Sometimes if you simply save a file, and simply read it again your code won't "find" it, unless you escape or strip all these characters properly.

The client filename could possibly pose a risk, if the name could have for example a path embedded into it. A presented filename such as "../../../../home/user/file" could possibly trick your program into overwriting a file, as long as the permissions were very badly implemented and you are simply concatenating paths. At worst I'd say this would be an annoyance or DoS attack - limited to overwriting gzip files and "breaking" them.

The client filename could possibly overwrite another user's files? I'm not sure what your namespacing is, but a clever attacker could try to trick another user into downloading their xml/sql file by naming it cleverly.

Also if you could guess someone else's filename, you could guess the resulting URLs and war-dial through them looking for content.

All of these risks would go away, if you used a nice GUID to name the file. Or mapped it to each user's session (e.g. file1.gz is only valid to that user's session).

I generally don't use client names, or seriously validate and clean them before re-presenting them.

Answer (score 2):

The main risk of uploading files with php (and other interpreted languages, as a matter of fact) is that user can upload a `.php` file and **if it's stored inside a web-root**, then execute it.

From your question, it seems you only allow certain non `.php` extensions. Make sure you do this check on server-side, not just on the client. Also, if you don't need to serve the uploaded file on web afterwards, store it outside of your web-root. If you force the filename and extension after upload (not keeping the original one), then you can have even more control over what's going on in your part of the system.

Other file types can also be exploited (images for example, see https://imagetragick.com/) so it's a good idea to check specifically for the file-types you want uploadable.

Comment: It's correct this is the biggest risk with uploads - I've seen it happen! The OP mentions using tmp_name which is usually in a /tmp/ folder well away from the web root (possibly excepting some really terrible shared hosts). So the original file won't be downloadable, only the gz processed file.